# ArgumentError: string contains null byte when use StringValueCStr

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

here is my [test file](https://gist.github.com/f4b388f84ce3e4fdf77b)

here is my full code (github.com/roroco/ro_article/tree/string-contains-null-byte)

I get "ArgumentError: string contains null byte" when run following code:

in ruby side:

```
get_article(File.read("test_file"))
```

In c side:

```
VALUE get_article(VALUE self, VALUE html) {
    str html2 = StringValueCStr(html);
```

the [test file](https://gist.github.com/f4b388f84ce3e4fdf77b) is so large, how to find null byte in this file? and how to make StringValueCStr work for all string even it contains "null byte"

Answer (score 2):

when I use following code:

```
body = File.read("test_file")
result = body.inspect
```

I have "result" contains "\u0000"(my encoding is utf8), so the solution is

```
body.gsub(%r{\u0000}, "")
```

do it in ruby side or c side